# Does the App Store review team report only the first bug they found?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

If App Store review team rejects your App, can you be sure that the issue they found is the only one? Or they just stop reviewing once they encounter an issue?

I'm asking because I'm not sure whether to double check the whole App or just fix the problem they found and go ahead once again. I'm not really into wasting another 9 days to wake up with another rejection.

So, do they report all the issues they found, or the first one they noticed? Are there anybody out there who got reported more than one bug?

It's worth to add that my rejection happend due to 2.3 paragraph which stands for:

> Apps that do not perform as advertised by the developer will be
>   rejected